# Is it possible to sign a powershell script with a snk file?

Tags: powershell

I have made a small powershell script (ps1 file) for internal use only.
To make it a little easier to execute the powershell script, I want to sign it.

We have a snk-file that we use to sign assemblies that we give to our customers.

Is it possible to sign the script with the snk file?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

```
.cer files are X.509 Certificates 

.pfx files are encrypted X.509 Certificates using a password-based symmetric key

.snk files only contain the RSA key (public/private or public only)
```

The `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet have a param `-Certificate` that accept

```
[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]
```

then you need a certificate. You can read this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/94252) on SuperUser for more info about sign a powershell script.